How to reduce my Tensorflow docker image?
I have a Dash app running fine locally. The app uses tensorflow and ultralytics to detect some events on a graph using yolo8. I am trying to deploy this app to a server inside a docker container. The first image I built was based on the tensorflow:latest-gpu docker image. The resulting image size was 19,5 Gb. removing the -gpu tag helped reduce the size to 14Gb. Then I tried building from a python image (3.11.0). The python based image was 13Gb.
How can I further reduce the size of my image? 13Gb is a lot considering that my dash app folder containing the assets is about 6Mb.
Here are my Dockerfile:
#Using python
FROM python:3.11.0
COPY requirements.txt ./requirements.txt
# install opencv dependencies and requirements
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install ffmpeg libsm6 libxext6  -y && pip install -r requirements.txt --ignore-installed
#Copy files to container
COPY . ./
#Running APP and doing some PORT Forwarding
CMD gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:1312 app:server

and requirements file:
dash==2.16.1
dash-core-components==2.0.0
dash-daq==0.5.0
dash-html-components==2.0.0
dash-table==5.0.0
gunicorn==21.2.0
influxdb-client==1.41.0
keras==3.0.5
numpy==1.26.4
opencv-python==4.9.0.80
pandas==2.2.1
pillow==10.2.0
plotly==5.20.0
tensorflow==2.16.1
ultralytics==8.1.27
kaleido

Thanks for your help !

Hi @The Governor Utilize multi-stage builds to separate the build environment from the runtime environment. This allows you to install dependencies and build your application in one stage and then copy only the necessary files to the final stage.Instead of using a full Python image, consider using a slim base image such as python:3.11.0-slim or python:3.11.0-alpine. These images are smaller in size compared to the full Python image.If your Dash app contains static assets (e.g., images, CSS files), consider compressing them before copying them into the Docker image.

Hey @PriyaT, thanks for your reply ! I will try these options !
